# arping in c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, ethernet, libpcap, arp

I was wondering if anyone knows of a arping api or wrapper written in c++ not c ? I have looked at the libpcap library but I want a c++ alternative if possible

http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html

[Programmatic use of ARP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451737/programmatic-use-of-arp)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libpcap's APIs should be callable from C++, at least in newer versions that have `extern "C"` wrappers in the header files.

Comment: I have used libpcap before I was wondering if there was a new library available ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it will work http://libpcappp.sourceforge.net/ libpcap++